# jQuery adding a dropdown item fail sorting in Chrome

Tags: jquery, append

I am trying to add dynamically items in a dropdown in a specific order. in FF it works, on IE and Chrome it does not.

here's my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>How to add option to drop down list</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
div.demo
{
float:left;
padding:25px;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

$('.demoButton').click(function(){
var optionList={

'firefox':'Mozilla firefox',
'chrome':'Google chrome',
'1':'awesome'
};

$.each(optionList,function(val,text){

$('.demoDropDown').append($('<option></option>').val(val).html(text));
});

});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="demo">
<button class="demoButton">Click to add option</button>
</div>
<div class="demo">
<select class="demoDropDown">
<option>--Select--</option>
</select>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I should see:

Firefox
Chrome
Awesome

but I get:

awesome
Firefox
Chrome

am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using an object, you have no guarantee that they will come back in any order.  You should use an array of objects if you need the order to be preserved.

```
var optionList=[
  {val: 'firefox', text: 'Mozilla firefox'},
  {val: 'chrome', text: 'Google chrome'},
  {val: '1', text: 'awesome'}
];
$.each(optionList,function(){
  $newOption = $('<option></option>').html(this.text).attr('value', this.val);
  $('.demoDropDown').append($newOption);
});
```